# Translating a dataframe with a second dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two text files:

One with translations/aliases of the form:

```
123 456
2 278
456 99999
...
```

and another one with three entries per line:

```
34 456 9900
111 333 444
234 2 562
...
```

I want to translate the second column, if possible, so for example I would like the output dataframe to have the rows:

```
34, 99999, 9900
111, 333, 444
234, 278, 562
```

Reading in the text files works fine. However, I do have problems with translating the column b.
This is my basic code structure right now:

```py
translation = sc.textFile("transl.txt")\
    .map(lambda line: line.split(" "))

def translate(string):
    x = translation.filter(lambda x: x[0] == string).collect()
    if x == []:
        return string
    return x[0][1]

d = sc.textFile("text.txt")\
    .map(lambda line: line.split(" "))\
    .toDF(["a", "b", "c"])\
    .withColumn("b", translate(d.b))\
```

Everything works fine exept for the last line.
I know that applying functions to a column in spark doesn't work that easy, however I am out of ideas how else to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with a [left join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join). Please have a look at the commented code below:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

l1 = [
(123, 456)
,(2, 278)
,(456, 99999)
]

l2 = [
(34, 456, 9900)
,(111, 333, 444)
,(234, 2, 562)
]

df1=spark.createDataFrame(l1, ['one1', 'two1'])
df2=spark.createDataFrame(l2, ['one2', 'two2', 'three2'])

#creates an dataframe with five columns one1, two1, one2, two2, three2
df = df2.join(df1, df2.two2 == df1.one1 , 'left')

#checks if a value in your dictionary dataframe is avaiable, if not it will keep the current value
#otherwise the value will be translated
df = df.withColumn('two2', F.when(F.col('two1').isNull(), F.col('two2') ).otherwise(F.col('two1')))

df = df.drop('one1', 'two1')

df.show()
```

Output:

```py
+----+-----+------+
|one2| two2|three2|
+----+-----+------+
| 111|  333|   444|
| 234|  278|   562|
|  34|99999|  9900|
+----+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach would be to join the two files, if you imported them as dataframes. I've shown an example below:

```
# Sample DataFrame's from provided example
import pandas as pd
translations = pd.DataFrame({
    'Key': [123,2,456],
    'Translation': [456,278,99999]
    })  

entries = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [34,11,234],
    'B': [456,333,2],
    'C': [9900,444,562]
    })
```

After importing the files we can merge them by the lookup keys, using a left join

```
df = pd.merge(entries, translations, left_on='B', right_on='Key', how='left')
```

However, this will leave us with a columns with NaN's where a lookup couldn't be found. To resolve this, we take the value from 'B', and at the same time overwrite the original 'B' column with our lookup value.

```
df['B'] = df['Translation'].mask(pd.isna, df['B'])
```

Now we need to drop the additional columns to arrive at the result that you requested:

```
df.drop(columns=['Key', 'Translation'])
```

df will now look like this:

```
    A   B       C
0   34  99999   9900
1   11  333     444
2   234 278     562
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I am looking for a solution with pyspark dataframes and not pandas.